# Do Sonar have disable nosonar for next line?

Tags: sonarqube, eslint, lint

from the question above I need to know that can we close sonar for next line same in eslint?

example from eslint

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
while(true) {
```

now I have to disable both of eslint and sonar like this

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
  while (true) { // NOSONAR [disable sonar; to keep polling work]
```

I would like to know is it possible that can close sonar for the next line.

Thank you.